# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname as a result for android consuming WCF restful web services

Tags: android, json, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm trying to call my wcf webservices from android but while reading the response stream all I got is this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
\n<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
\n<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
\n</BODY></HTML>\n
```

and this is my client side

```
String result = "";
    String url ="http://10.0.2.2:81/WScom.svc/GetUserList";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.toString();
    }

    try {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        //System.out.println(line);
    }

    result = sb.toString();

        is.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

        result = e.toString();
    }
    return (result);
}
```

although when I paste the link in a browser ( of course with a localhost instead of 10.0.2.2 because of the android emulator requirement ) it display a perfect json result !  so any help please ?

Comment: What happens when you open browser in android phone and give the url?

Comment: same error bad request and Invalid host name !

Comment: Is your phone connected to internet?  Your phone is not able to resolve the IP.  No problem with your server.

Comment: yeah it's connected I can open any other link

Comment: (1)  Are you using any proxy?  (b)  On your desktop/laptop instead of localhost did you trying giving the ip and try?

Comment: I'm not using any proxy but when I ping the 10.0.2.2 adress I recieve nothing on my laptop

Comment: It is also dependent on port.  Did you try on laptop this URL?  http://10.0.2.2:81/WScom.svc/GetUserList

Comment: well it's inaccessable ! it's loading that link to forever

Comment: ah that is the problem.  do ipconfig.  that will give you correct ip.

Comment: okay I found my exact ip and replace it with the 10.0.2.2 adress and I got the same error bad request and Invalid host name ! actually even in my browser if I replace local host with my current IP adress I got the same error

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is what you mentioned earlier.  What is the exact IP?  when you type ipconfig from command prompt you should get the ip.  suppose http://localhost:81/ works for your http://<Ip of ipconfigoutput>:81 should also work.

Comment: the 10.0.2.2 is the conventional ip used to test with android emulatorn but for me it's not accessible surprisingly my actual Ip:81 doesn't work but localhost:81  does !